# Change Wep-Part properties

Tags: sharepoint-server

How to change web part properties from content editor to a list view
I connected the web part to a document library but documents were not listed in that web part.
When I checked the properties, I found out that, it was created as a content editor, but I cannot see the option to change it to a list view:
in tha attached screenshot, you can see two web parts
 - for the document web part we can add more files to that library
 - for the Policy & Procedures web part, i need also to link it to a library and be able to add files, but when i go to its web part properties, i cant find the options to link it to library[image]

Comment: Please provide more information and some screenshots for helping solving your issue. I cannot accurately understand your issue. Do you want to display a document library in a web part? Or you want to edit the view of a web part?

Comment: Dear Allen, i updated my question with more explanation and attached an image,
i dont know how to reply direct to your message, 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding about the content editor web part.

We can use the Content Editor Web Part to add formatted text, tables, hyperlinks, and images to a Web Part Page. Usually, we use the Content Editor Web Part to add:

1. An introductory, formatted paragraph to a page.
2. A table of instructions to explain a chart on your page, the data that is used in the chart, and how the chart was created.
3. A set of hyperlinks to more information.

However, Content Editor Web Part is not designed to connect to a Web site. That means we cannot display a library in a content editor web part. Check more information about the content editor web part:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc

The right(Documents) web part in your picture is a list web part. When you create a list or library on your site, a Web Part of the same name as the list or library is automatically created. For example, if you create a library called Documents A, a Web Part called Documents A will be available in a web part page. The Web Part automatically displays the data contained in the list or library that you created.

If you want to display another library in your page, you can add this library web part in this page.

[image]